# Check if function input is a System.IO.FileInfo or a string object?

Tags: powershell

This seems to work on my Terminal, It will correctly Identify the Object Type:

```
If ($var.getType().name -eq 'DirectoryInfo'){'File IO Obj'}else{'String Obj'}
```

But inside a function it falls apart:

```
Function Test{
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Position = 1)]
        $InputObect
        )
            If ($input.getType().name -eq 'DirectoryInfo')Else{'Something Else'}
}
```

I tried this as well:

```
Function Test{
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Position = 1)]
        $InputObect
        )
        $global:var = $InputObect
}
```

Checking on terminal the type of `$Var`  with `$var.getType().FullName` returns `System.Object[]`

I have tried searching but this is all I could turn up.

I am simply looking to identify the type of file piped/sent in, then use `If` or `Else` to do something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `System.Object[]` denotes an array. How are you calling the function? Are you actually piping something into the function like `Get-ChildItem | Test` or do you call it with a parameter like `Test -InputObject (Get-ChildItem)`? In the first case the function will receive file objects one by one, in the latter it will receive a single array of file objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function Test {
    Param (
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$FileObject
    )

    Write-Host ($FileObject -eq $null)
    if ($FileObject -eq $null) {
        return $null
    }

    if ($FileObject.GetType() -eq [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
        Write-Host ("Input is file object")
    }

    Write-Host ($FileObject.FullName)
}

Test -FileObject ([System.IO.FileInfo]::new("C:\users\user\documents\file.txt"))
```

Define the required type within in the parameter declaration to make it easy to understand what is required.

If you want to accepted multiple types you can do it like this:

```
function Test {
    Param (
        $IoObject
    )

    if ($IoObject -eq $null) {
        return $null
    }
    
    if (($IoObject.GetType() -eq [System.IO.FileInfo]) -or ($IoObject.GetType() -eq [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])) {
        Write-Host ("Input is file object or directory object")
    }
}
```

You could also check for  `GetType().BaseType -eq [System.IO.FileSystemInfo]` which should be true for Directories and Files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to address this use case.

Getting the object type directly - for example select the first object returned for a directory or a file:

```
# Directory
((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Directory)[0]).GetType().Name
# Results
<#
DirectoryInfo
#>

# File
((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File)[0]).GetType().Name
# Results
<#
FileInfo
#>
```

Then just directly compare the results in one line

```
# Folder and file
(((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Directory)[0]).GetType().Name).CompareTo(((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File)[0]).GetType().Name)
# Results
<#
-1
#>
```

File and file

```
(((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File)[0]).GetType().Name).CompareTo(((Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -File)[0]).GetType().Name)
# Results
<#
0
#>
```

As a full function

```
Clear-Host
Function Test-InputObjectType
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
       Short description

    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description

      # Use this as an example of case sensitive string matching

      .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this function

    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this function
    #>
    
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('tiot')]

    param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, 
        Position = 1)]
        $InputObject
    )

    # Initialize GUI resources
    # ...

    # Required for use with web SSL sites
    # ...

    #region       Begin Script ---
    #
    If  ((((Get-ChildItem -Path $InputObject -Directory)[0]).GetType().Name) -eq 'DirectoryInfo')
        {"$InputObject is of type DirectoryInfo"}
    Else {"$InputObject is of type FileInfo"}

    #
    #endregion    EndScript --- 
}

Test-InputObjectType -InputObject 'D:\Temp'
# Results
<#
D:\Temp is of type DirectoryInfo
#>


Test-InputObjectType -InputObject 'D:\Temp\arp_IPA.txt'
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\arp_IPA.txt is of type FileInfo
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into situations where my $Array.GetType() and its properties might just report I was looking at a [System.Object], maybe I'm casting those wrong, but in some cases $Array[0] ends up reporting a different type than $Array.

Grabbing the string containing the object type out of Get-Member, objectizing it and returning that, has worked great no matter what kind of mess I pass into it:

```
Function Get-Type { 
    if ($Args -eq $Null) {Write-Host -f Red "`n  Must pass in $Args to get type name of.`n"}
    $Result = $Args | % { 
        $_ | % {
            $_ | % {
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    TypeName="$((($_ | Get-Member | Out-String -Stream) | Select-String "TypeName:").ToString().Trim().Split(' ')[1])"; 
                    Object="$_"; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Return $Result
}
```

It's perfectly happy to get you the types of even mixed sets of object types two layers deep, like this combination of a string and a set of files:

```
PS C:\temp> get-type @('ThisOneIsAString',(gci *.log))

TypeName           Object
--------           ------
System.String      ThisOneIsAString
System.IO.FileInfo C:\temp\FtpSessionLogExcerpts-2023-04-27.log
System.IO.FileInfo C:\temp\UninstalItems.log


PS C:\temp> get-type 'Just a string'

TypeName      Object
--------      ------
System.String Just a string
```